# Sweealert2 : Unknown parameter icon

Tags: sweetalert2

I'm using sweealert2 on my project here's my code

header include js via jsdeliver.net

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

Jquery Version : jQuery v3.4.1

Script on footer

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#updateUserProfile").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: form.serialize(), 
           success: function(data)
           {
                $('.modal').modal('hide');
                var hasil = $.parseJSON(data);
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'info',
                    title: hasil.message,
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    timer: 1500
                });
                // Swal.fire('Success', hasil.message, 'success', 1500)
                setTimeout(function(){
                    window.location.reload(1);
                }, 1500);
           }
         });
    });
});
</script>
```

ERROR on console.log

```
SweetAlert2: Unknown parameter "icon"
```

but when i use like this no error, and icon showing up

```
Swal.fire('Success', hasil.message, 'success', 1500)
```

Comment: [SOLVED] problem solved when I add js and css locally on my server.

Comment: Older versions of SweetAlert2 had "type" and latest one has "icon" in its place.
https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/releases/tag/v9.0.0

Comment: thanks. This was troubling me. I'll upgrade to later version of swal2.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

try switch "icon", for "type", like this:

```html
               Swal.fire({
                    type: 'info',
                    title: hasil.message,
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    timer: 1500
                });
```

I just had the same problem and found this solution!

Comment: remember, use this solution only if you want to keep sweetalert2 version 8.x, like in the time of this writing cdnjs from libman could only deliver 8.x version, but unpkg delivers it at 9.x which use "icon" parameter name!

Comment: comments like this are probably frowned upon, but this is one I wish I could upvote a few times.  It saved a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 5):

The new major version (v9) was released a couple of days ago, please update your `sweetalert2` dependency:

`package.json`:

```js
"sweetalert2": "^9.0.0",
```

Or, if you're using CDN:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
```

Read the release notes to see all breaking changes: https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/releases/tag/v9.0.0